# getAttribute("value") works in simulator but it returns null in a device

Tags: ionic-framework, selenium-chromedriver, appium, hybrid-mobile-app, stenciljs

I'm using Appium over Android in a hybrid app made with stenciljs and ionic.

I'm using Appium server GUI and these are my capabilities:

```
            caps.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
            caps.setCapability("platformVersion", "11");
            caps.setCapability("deviceName", "emulator-5558");
            caps.setCapability("automationName", "UiAutomator2");
            caps.setCapability("udid", "emulator-5558");
            caps.setCapability("app",androidAppPath);
            driver = new AndroidDriver(appiumUrl, caps);
```

One of my test check if the text in a particular input field is equal to an expected text

To access to the input text I use:

```
WebElement input = webElement.findElement(inputBy);

input.getAttribute("value")
```

I double checked the input field is the right webelement.

My problem is that I am able to get the text from the input field if I run the test in an Android simulator, so the test will pass.

But If I run the test in an Android device, `input.getAttribute("value")` will always return `null`.

My understanding is that ChromeDriver is embedded in Appium, so if I run the test in the simulator or in the device, there should no be any difference in the capabilities.

Also my app has the `setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled` property on the `android.webkit.WebView` set to true

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

It seems the problem is related with "w3c"

So I had to deactivate this capability with:

```
            caps.setCapability("appium:chromeOptions", ImmutableMap.of("w3c", false));
```